# Marketing Cloud passing value into URL using email template from sendable data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpagesurl

I am passing a value into email template button using sendable DE

My values are `email`, `firstname`, `contacttime` (Null)

```
<a href="%%=RedirectTo(CloudPagesURL(2042))=%%" target="_blank" style="color: #002f6c; text-decoration: none;">MORNING</a>`
```

When user clicks on Morning button I want that value on to redirect thank you page URL and update it to DE is this possible?

Answer (score 5):

First, you need to include name and value pairs for all parameters that you want to pass from email to a CloudPage:

```
%%=CloudPagesURL(ID, 'CampaignCode', @CampCode, 'SegmentName', @SegmentName)=%%
```

Then on a CloudPage, use the RequestParameter function to retrieve the values.

Documentation:

CloudPagesURL: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/cloudpagesurl.htm

RequestParameter: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/requestparameter.htm

Then on the CloudPage, you need to use the UpdateData function to update a DE, here’s an example from ampscript.guide:

```
%%[

var @emailAddress, @newFirstName, @rowsUpdated

set @emailAddress = AttributeValue("emailaddr") /* value from attribute or DE column in send context */
set @emailAddress = "doug@limedash.com" /* or a literal value */

set @newFirstName = "Douglas"

set @rowsUpdated  = UpdateData("LoyaltyMembers",1,"EmailAddress", @emailAddress, "FirstName", @newFirstName)

]%%
```

Read more about it here: https://ampscript.guide/updatedata/